# Closed set in product topology which is not in any product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

**Definition** On the Cartesian product $Y\times Z$ let $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{C}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of all "rectangles" $B\times C$ with $B\in\mathcal{B}$ and $C\in\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{C}$ is called the *product $\sigma$-algebra* on $Y\times Z$.

**Definition** The collection $2^\mathbb{N}$ of all subsets of a countably infinite set is said to have cardinality
$c$, or the cardinality of the continuum.

Show that for some topological spaces $(X,\mathcal{S})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T})$, there is a closed set $D$ in $X\times Y$ with product topology which is not in *any* product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$, for example if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are the Borel $\sigma$-algebras for the given topologies.

*Hint*: Let $X=Y$ be a set with cardinality greater than $c$, for example, the set $2^I$ of all subsets of $I:=[0,1]$. Let $D$ be the diagonal {$(x,x):x\in X$}. Show that for each $C\in\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$, there are sequences {$A_n$} $\subset\mathcal{A}$ and {$B_n$} $\subset\mathcal{B}$ such that $C$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by {$A_n\times B_n$}$_{n\geq1}$. For each $n$, let $x=_nu$ mean $x\in A_n$ if and only if $u\in A_n$. Define a relation $x\equiv u$ iff for all $n,x=_n u$. Show that this is an equivalence relation which has at most $c$ different equivalence classes, and for any $x,y,$ and $u$, if $x\equiv u$, then $(x,y)\in C$ if and only if $(u,y)\in C$. For $C=D$ and $y=x$, find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=Y$ be the set of all functions from $I$ into {0, 1}. Let $X$ have the product topology. Then the basis element of $X$ is in the form of $\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ where $U_i=$ {0} or {1} for finitely many $i$ and $U_i=$ {0, 1} for all the remaining $i$'s. It happens that an open set of $X$ is also in this form. $\mathcal{A}$ is generated by $\prod_{i\in I}U_i$. By taking countable intersection, $\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ with countably many $U_i=$ {0} or {1} is also in $\mathcal{A}$. Taking complement and union do not produce more elements. Thus each member of $\mathcal{A}$ is in the form of $\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ with countably many $U_i=$ {0} or {1}.

Note that $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}$. $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$ is generated by $\prod_{i\in I}U_i\times\prod_{j\in I}U_j$ with countably many $U_i=$ {0} or {1}. Making complement, intersection and union do not produce new members. Thus each $C\in\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$ is in the form of $\prod_{i\in I}U_i\times\prod_{j\in I}U_j$ with countably many $U_i=$ {0} or {1}. Take out the $U_i$'s with $U_i=$ {0} or {1}. Order the index $i$ with positive integers. Let $f(i)$ be the corresponding integer for $i$. Then $f(i)$ is injective. Similarly, take out the $U_j$'s with $U_j=$ {0} or {1}. Order the index $j$ with positive integers. Let $g(j)$ be the corresponding integer for $j$. Let $A_n=\prod_{i\in I}U_i$ with $U_i=$ {0, 1} for all $i$ except $i=f^{-1}(n)$. Let $U_{f^{-1}(n)}$ of $A_n$ equal to the $U_{f^{-1}(n)}$ of the first coordinate of $C$. Similarly, let $B_n=\prod_{j\in I}U_j$ with $U_j=$ {0, 1} for all $i$ except $j=g^{-1}(n)$. Let $U_{g^{-1}(n)}$ of $B_n$ equal to the $U_{g^{-1}(n)}$ of the second coordinate of $C$. Then $C$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by {$A_n\times B_n$}$_{n\geq1}$.

For each $n$, let $x=_nu$ mean $x\in A_n$ if and only if $u\in A_n$. $x=_nu$ iff $x$ and $u$ have the same coordinate at $i=f^{-1}(n)$. $x\equiv u$ iff $x$ and $u$ have the same coordinates at $i=f^{-1}(n)$ for all $n$. This is an equivalence relation. There are at most $c$ different equivalence classes since it is either 0 or 1 at these countably many coordinates.

Note that $(x,y)\in C$ iff the $i=f^{-1}(n)$ coordinates of $x$ and the $j=g^{-1}(n)$ coordinates of $y$ are in $\pi_i(A_n)$ and $\pi_j(B_n)$, respectively, where $\pi_i$ is the coordinate projection function. For any $x,y,$ and $u$, if $x\equiv u$, then $(x,y)\in C$ if and only if $(u,y)\in C$. This holds since the $y$-part has been taken care and $x\equiv u$ guarantees the coordinate requirement of $x$-part.

For $C=D$ and $y=x$, obviously $(x,y)\in C$. Let $x\equiv u$. Then $(u,y)\in C$. This is a contradiction. The definition of $D$ requires strict diagonal, i.e., all the uncountably many coordinates in $I$ should be the same, but $x\equiv u$ only requires countably many of them are same.

$D$ is diagonal, so it is closed in $X\times Y$. But $D$ is not in *any* product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{B}$. If it is in, a contradiction occurs as is shown.